# SPSS looping through a set of variables in combination with if-statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, vector, spss

I've got 53 variables named W1_C14_0 to W1_C14_52, and each has a value from 1 to 15. I need to find how many "spells" of each number there are in this list - i.e. how many seperate runs of 1's, 2's etc in each case. This is what I'm doing and it's working fine, but is there any way to condense it into a loop?

```
DO REPEAT first = W1_C14_0 to W1_C14_51 /
second = W1_C14_1 to W1_C14_52 .
   DO IF (SYSMIS(first) OR first<>second) .
      DO IF (second=1) . 
         COMPUTE W1_spells1 = W1_spells1 + 1 .
      ELSE IF (second=2) .
         COMPUTE W1_spells2 = W1_spells2 + 1 .
      ELSE IF (second=3) .
         COMPUTE W1_spells3 = W1_spells3 + 1 .

      *and so on down to...

      ELSE IF (second=15) .
         COMPUTE W1_spells15 = W1_spells15 + 1 .
      END IF.
   END IF.
END REPEAT .
```

Comment: You will need to be more specific about what counts as a run and how you want the data in the end. If you had a set `11112222` what would the result be? How about `12121212` or `11221122` or `1112223` etc.? You may find some motivation from this [NABBLE question](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Detecting-response-patterns-td5718847.html), or I might consider using `VARSTOCASES` and using the `LAG` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the spell variables using the `VECTOR` command.

```
VECTOR W1_spells = W1_spells1 TO W1_spells15.

DO REPEAT first = W1_C14_0 to W1_C14_51 /
second = W1_C14_1 to W1_C14_52 .
   DO IF (SYSMIS(first) OR first<>second).
      LOOP #i=1 TO 15.
         DO IF (second=#i) . 
            COMPUTE W1_spells(#i) = W1_spells(#i) + 1.
         END IF.
      END LOOP.
   END IF.
END REPEAT.
```